# How to convert Outlook.MailItem attachment to inputstream?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, outlook-addin

I would like to save attachments into AWS bucket when getting an email in outlook account.
I tried with `HttpPostedFileBase`, which has `InputStream` property.

I tried like below

```
//successfully saving 'HttpPostedFileBase' files

using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) {
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest {
        BucketName = _bucketName,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
        Key = string.Format("uploads/" + AssignedTaskId.ToString() + "/" + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)),
        InputStream = postedFile.InputStream
    };
    s3client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
}

//but cannot get from Outlook.MailItem attachments

Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;
foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems) {
    newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
}
using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) {
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest {
        BucketName = _bucketName,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
        Key = string.Format("uploads/{0}", newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName),
        InputStream = newEmail.Attachments[i].InputStream
    };
    s3client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
}
}
```

Getting an error:

> 'Attachment' does not contain a definition for 'InputStream' and no accessible extension method 'InputStream' accepting a first argument of type 'Attachment' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property for that. Instead, you can access a low-level property:

```
 const string PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

 Outlook.Attachment attachment = mail.Attachments[0];  

 // Retrieve the attachment as a byte array
 var attachmentData = attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN);
```

Another option is to save the attachment (see `Attachment.SaveAsFile`) to a file, then open the file as a byte stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but getting an error : cannot implicit convert type byte[] to 'System.Io.Stream'

Comment: Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

Comment: PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN) will not work for large attachments.